# Does SHA1 require public keys?

Tags: hash

I want to know if they do, and if they don't which ones don't require public keys.

Comment: SHA1 doesn't have a concept of keys at all. It's just a hash function.

Comment: SHA does not stand for Signature&HAndshake!

Answer (score 4):

I guess this confusion is due to OpenSSL command line (`openssl dgst` if I'm not mistaken) or functions such as Java's `"SHAwithRSA"`. However, *signature verification* commonly *uses* a hash over the message to perform the operation as well as a public key. It is not the hash itself that accepts a public key. In that sense, such interfaces are badly named.

A hash has only one input: a variable sized message encoded as bits (generally only full bytes are supported), and a single statically sized output. There is no way that they accept a public key, except if it is input as encoded value, but then it would just be treated as part of the input message.

Read the [PKCS #1: RSA Cryptography Specifications Version 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) to understand how the hash is used.